# Page For Entering One-time-password Does Not Appear After Sending OTP to User Using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working on a class project, but I am stuck a little bit.

I am working on a login form, which authorizes a user to enter a one-time-password that is being sent to the user's email.

So far, the otp and the current time and date are being saved to the database successfully.

I have also managed to send the code to the user's email but once it is sent, the page does not navigate to the form where the user is supposed to enter the one-time-password.

All that works is this part here:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
        .
        .
        .
    <div class="form-top-left">
        <h3>Log in</h3>
      </div>
         <div class="form-top-right">
            <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
         </div>
        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
        <?php if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>   
        <div class="error-message"><?php if(isset($error_message)) echo $error_message; ?></div>
        <?php } ?> 
        <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="form_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" name="form_password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" name="login" value="Sign in">

        <div class="text-center">
        <a href="wlt_passwordreset.php" class="forgot-password">
            Forgot the password?
        </a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <form class="form-signin" action="http://localhost/Dreamweaver/regist.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signup">
        .
        .
        .
    </form>
```

What could be the problem?? Can someone please help me on this.Thank you.

Here is the html part:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-inverse" href="http://localhost/Dreamweaver/index.php"><img src="img/neza.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->

 </nav>
    </div>

   <div class="container">
   <div class="card card-container"> 
   <form class="form-signin" method="post" action=""> 
   <?php 
    if($success == 1) { 
   ?>
            <div class="form-wrap">
              <h2>A verification code has been sent to <?php  $row["form_email"] ?>. Please enter it below to verify your account.</h2>
                        <?php if(!empty($error_message)) { ?> 
      <div class="error-message"><?php if(isset($error_message)) echo $error_message; ?></div>
         <?php } ?> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="key">Verification Code:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="otp" id="key" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" name="submit_otp" value="Verify Account">
     <h2>Did not receive the verification code?</h2>
                 <!---- <form id="login-form"> ------>
          <input type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-custom1 btn-lg btn-block" value="Resend Code">
                <!----- </form> ----->
           </div> <!---/form-wrap----->
  <?php 
  } elseif ($success == 2) {
   header("Location: fomu.php");
  }else {
     ?>
      <div class="form-top-left">
        <h3>Log in</h3>
      </div>
         <div class="form-top-right">
            <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
         </div>
        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
        <?php if(!empty($error_message)) { ?> 
  <div class="error-message"><?php if(isset($error_message)) echo $error_message; ?></div>
  <?php } ?> 
        <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="form_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" name="form_password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" name="login" value="Sign in">
            
        <div class="text-center">
        <a href="wlt_passwordreset.php" class="forgot-password">
            Forgot the password?
        </a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <form class="form-signin" action="http://localhost/Dreamweaver/regist.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signup">
        </form>
         <?php 
  }
  ?>
    </form>
    </div><!-- /card-container -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="text-centre">
      <a class="text-new" href="#">Privacy|</a>
      <a class="text-new" href="#">Security|</a>
      <a class="text-new" href="#">Fees</a>
                    </div>
       </div> <!---/row--->
       
      </div> <!---/container--->
     </div><!-- /container1--> 

    

     <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


    <script src="logwin.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mscript.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the dbtest.php used to INSERT TO the db:

```
<?php
class DBController {
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $password = "myPassword";
private $database = "myDB";
private $conn;

function __construct() {
    $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
}

function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
    return $conn;
}

function runQuery($query) {
    $resultset = [];
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
        return $resultset;
}

function numRows($query) {
    $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    return $rowcount;   
}

function updateQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($this->conn));
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}

function insertQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($this->conn));
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}

function deleteQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($this->conn));
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
function generate_OTP($length = 8, $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRQSTUVWXYZ0123456789'){
            $chars_length = (strlen($chars) - 1);
            $string = $chars{rand(0, $chars_length)};
                for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i = strlen($string)){
                $r = $chars{rand(0, $chars_length)};
                    if ($r != $string{$i - 1}) $string .=  $r;
                }
                return $string;
            }
function getConn(){
    return $this->conn;
}
}
?>
```

Here is the PHP code that I am referring to:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$success = "";
require_once('dbtest.php');
$db = new DBController();
if(isset($_POST["login"])) {
   $result = $db->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE 
   form_email='" . $_POST["form_email"] . "' AND status = 'active' ");
 if (!empty($result)){
    foreach($result as $row){
        //Verify password
         if ( $row['form_password'] === crypt( $_POST["form_password"], $row['form_password'] ) ) {
            $otp = $db->generate_OTP();
            require_once("mail_function.php");
            $mail_status = sendOTP($_POST["form_email"],$otp);
            if($mail_status == 1) {
            $query = "UPDATE registered_users SET `otp` = '" . $otp . "', `is_expired` = 0, `create_at` = '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). "'  WHERE form_email = '" . $_POST["form_email"] . "'";
            $result = $db->updateQuery($query);
                if(!empty($result)){
                $current_id = mysqli_insert_id($db->getConn());
                        if(!empty($current_id)) {
                            $success = 1;
                        }
                }
            } 
         }
         else {
             $error_message = "Email or password is incorrect!";
         }
    }
}
else {
     $error_message = "Email or password is incorrect!";
     }
}
if(isset($_POST["submit_otp"])) {
  $result = $db->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE otp='" . $_POST["otp"] . "' AND is_expired!=1 AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(create_at, INTERVAL 24 HOUR)");
if(!empty($result)) {
    $query = "UPDATE registered_users SET `is_expired` = 1 WHERE otp = '" . $_POST["otp"] . "'";
    $result = $db->updateQuery($query);
    $success = 2;   
}else {
    $success = 1;
    $error_message = "Invalid OTP!";
 }  
}
?>
```

Comment: can you rephrase this? I can understand it : `"...but once it is sent, the form for entering the one-time-password does not appear-the part for entering the user email sticks on the page"`

Comment: Sorry, I mean the page does not navigate to the form where the user is supposed to enter the one-time-password.I hope this sounds better.Thank you

Comment: why do you have the `<html>` tag inside the `<form>` tag? also the `<html>` should only be used once at the beginning to open it and end at the end to close it.

Comment: @CodeGodie Only this part of the form works: <div>Enter Your Login Email</div>
  <div><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="login-input" required></div>
  <div><input type="submit" name="submit_email" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit"></div>

Comment: Thanks @CodeGodie silly of me not to have noted that gross mistake.Thank you very much. It worked!

Comment: @CodeGodie sorry I just noted that it worked because I had included a header redirecting the user to one-time-password page, but after excluding it, the problem still persists. Kindly help. Thank you

Comment: k ill continue inspecting

Comment: Thank you for your help @CodeGodie

Comment: no problem. What do you get when you print `var_dump($current_id)` from `$current_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);`?

Comment: I get this error: Notice: Undefined variable: current_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dreamweaver\php-login-with-otp-authentication\index.php on line 22
NULL

Comment: is your SQL `INSERT INTO otp_expiry` working? are you seeing the data in the DB?

Comment: can you show how the function `insertQuery()` used in `$db_handle->insertQuery` looks like?

Comment: Yes @CodeGodie the INSERT TO is working. Let me paste the code here. Thank you

Comment: I tried adding it to this comment box but it was too long. Kindly check it in the question part. I have included it as well. Thanks for your help @CodeGodie

Comment: @CodeGodie Or is there any other better way of implementing this because I tried to redirect the user to a different page having the OTP form, and even though it works, the user is logged in as long as he/she uses a password that exists in the database regardless of that whom it is meant for.

Comment: yea you can do it with sessions, but the way you have it should work.  For some reason one of your if statements is prob returning false, thus not getting to that success=1 area

Comment: @CodeGodie I'll really appreciate if you could help me with this. I have no problem with you helping me remotely through Teamviewer. Thank you so much

Comment: Okay let me try doing so right now. Thank you

Comment: updated my answer with something else i found. Try it.

Comment: I have do so but I get this error: `Notice: Undefined property: DBController::$getConn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dreamweaver\php-login-with-otp-authentication\index.php on line 22`

`Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dreamweaver\php-login-with-otp-authentication\index.php on line 22`

Comment: I really appreciate your willingness to help. I just cannot stop thanking you @CodeGodie

Comment: youre welcome, i like helping and coding.

Comment: I have already set up the Teamviewer @CodeGodie. Can I now send you my ID and password? Thank you

Comment: yes, you can go ahead.

Comment: got it, you can delete that comment. I will connect soon

Comment: lost connection for some reason

Comment: Too bad I lost connection. I had some problem with my internet connection. You really helped me @CodeGodie and I am so gratefully. I will take heed of your advice and once again many thanks.

Comment: @CodeGodie just one question on this please. After adding this method `function getConn(){
    return $this->conn;
}' I find some errors working with `mysqli_fetch_array().` I am using `if(!empty($result->num_rows)){while($rowcount = $result->fetch_assoc()){$row['password'];}}` Although there is no error displayed during the execution, there is no action taken on clicking submit. Where could I be going wrong?? Thank you for the help!

Comment: where is `$result` in `$result->num_rows` coming from ?

Comment: Here it is `$result = $db->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE form_email='" . $_POST["form_email"] . "' AND status = 'active' ");`

Comment: I have also changed the `while($rowcount = $result->fetch_assoc()){` to `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){`. I realized I'd made the mistake but that hasn't helped

Comment: i added UPDATE2 to my answer below. Try it.

Comment: Thank you very much @CodeGodie. You just saved me big time. Have never met such a nice person like you before! Be blessed

Comment: @CodeGodie please help me debug this code. I have tried as much as I can to find the problem but I haven't succeeded. Please help me check why it cannot navigate to the enter one-time-password section, just like the last code was behaving. I have edited my question to include the PHP code. Thank you

Comment: hey bud.. still having problems with this? Whats the problem?

Comment: Hi my friend @CodeGodie I actually realized where I was going wrong. I was using `mysqli_insert_id` yet in my new code, I was updating the row to include the generated OTP. So instead I decided to change the `mysqli_insert_id` with `mysqli_affected_rows` and it works perfectly. However, I was just wondering suppose two users are attempting to login subsequently, would it still work correctly for each user? Thank you.

Comment: yes it should still work correctly with multiple users as mysql stacks the requests in a queue like manner.

Comment: Thank you for the response @CodeGodie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad syntax: you have the `<html>` tag inside the `<form>`, that should not happen. The `<html>` should only be used once at the beginning to open it and end at the end to close it.

**UPDATE:**

Also, `mysqli_insert_id()` expects the link identifier of the last  `mysqli_connect` used. In your code, youre supplying it with `$conn`, but `$conn` is not whats being used in the `DBController` class.

To fix this:

1. add this method to you `DBController` class:

   ```
   function getConn(){
       return $this->conn;
   }
   ```
2. then change this:

   ```
   $result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
   if (!empty($result)) {
       $current_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
       if (!empty($current_id)) {
           $success = 1;
       }
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   $result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
   if (!empty($result)) {
       $current_id = mysqli_insert_id($db_handle->getConn());
       if (!empty($current_id)) {
           $success = 1;
       }
   }
   ```

**UPDATE2:**

You asked this *"After adding this method function `getConn(){ return $this->conn; }` I find some errors working with mysqli_fetch_array(). I am using `if(!empty($result->num_rows)){while($rowcount = $result->fetch_assoc()){$row['password'];}}`"*

look at what `runQuery()` does:

```
function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
}
```

it runs your SQL query, then if there are any results, it returns an array `$resultset`.. The problem is that you are not accounting for empty results. So lets add that, change it to this:

```
function runQuery($query) {
    $resultset = [];
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }
    return $resultset;
}
```

Now it will return an empty array, or an array with your results.

And you can call it with:

```
$result = $db->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE form_email='" . $_POST["form_email"] . "' AND status = 'active' ");
```

and use `$result` like this:

```
if(!empty($result)){
   foreach($result as $row){
      echo $row['password'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodeGodie